# Неудобство множественного наследования

Tags: интерфейс, множественное-наследование

В статье [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81_(%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)#.D0.98.D0.BD.D1.82.D0.B5.D1.80.D1.84.D0.B5.D0.B9.D1.81.D1.8B_.D0.B8_.D0.B0.D0.B1.D1.81.D1.82.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.BA.D1.82.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D0.BA.D0.BB.D0.B0.D1.81.D1.81.D1.8B)  об интерфейсах указано:

*На уровне исполнения классическая схема множественного наследования вызывает дополнительный ряд неудобств:*

*- если объект может параллельно наследовать n классов, существует n независимых способов к нему обращаться, а значит должно существовать (n — 1) дополнительных указателей на него; с точки зрения автоматического управления памятью это будет означать, что возникают ссылки, указывающие в середину объекта;*

Что значит "ссылки, указывающие в середину объекта", то есть в середину той части выделенной физической памяти которую занимает объект?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Представим ситуацию. У нас есть простой класс:

```
class A{
   int x;
}
class B{
   int y;
}   
class C:A,B{
}
```

Мы знаем, что указатель на наследника можно привести к указателю на базовый класс. Т.е.

```
C* p = new C(); //p - p = 0;
A* pp = (A*) p; //pp -p = 0;
```

Тут проблем нету, базовый класс лежит в начале объекта, указатель (его числовое значение) одинаковое.

Теперь `B* ppp = (B*) p; //ppp - p = sizeof(A)`.

Мы должны иметь указатель на начало блока B - класса. Но он идёт после блока класса А.

Это конечно чуть упрощено, но примерно так и есть.
Т.е. объект С - это объект А, потом объект B, потом его поля.

[Пример](http://ideone.com/IYunY7) на С++.

Comment: Итак, указатель (ссылку) на объект С мы приводим к указателям на базовые классы - A и B, и в порядке их приведения приходим к выводу, что "ссылка на середину объекта (С)" это указатель (ссылка) на объект B?

Comment: @ТимурВалиев можно и так сказать.

Comment: а что тогда в контексте сказанного было бы удобством (просто перевернуть проблему) множественного наследования? Что на что должно ссылаться?